# Error: no lwjgl64 in java.library.path in Eclipse when running Maven Test

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lwjgl, slick2d

### Problem: when I run maven test on my testclass, I get a build failure with the message:

```
no lwjgl64 in java.library.path
```

The normal Junit test works fine, and I have already added

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("natives").getAbsolutePath());
```

in the before method...

---

### The following points are what I tried next to the 'set property':

1) Added the lwjgl dependency to my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
  <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
  <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<lwjgl.version>2.9.3</lwjgl.version>
```

2) I have tried running:
 *please click on the image below*

[IMAGE: JRE VM argument: '-Djava.library.path=natives'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FKTG.jpg)

---

If someone could help me, it would be great! I hope i gave enough information.

---

My java build path:
[IMAGE: build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU5qL.jpg)

Comment: could you display your java build path to see if the lwjgl64  presente in the project lib

Comment: @Inforedaster I shall edit the post and take a picture of it :)

Comment: You put the library path as a relative path ('natives') and that makes it dependent on the local working directory that Eclipse sets if the directory is found or not. I think you need to make that absolute, something like `${workspace_loc}/PATH/TO/natives` so it doesn't matter what the current working directory is.

Comment: @Gimby I have done that in the java library path and in the vm arguments
"C:/ .... /natives" but it doesn't work

Comment: The [lwjgl documentation](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_Eclipse) makes no mention of setting the java.library.path variable in Eclipse, you just need to set the native library location for the lwjgl.jar file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
    <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <classifier>x64</classifier>
    <type>dll</type>
</dependency>
```

You will probably need to add the dll to your local repository, using:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lwjgl64.dll -DgroupId=org.lwjgl.lwjgl -DartifactId=lwjgl-Dversion=<x.xx> -Dpackaging=dll -DgeneratePom=true
```